# How to get the highest dominant color from google cloud vision api in python?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have a list of .jpg images and i am trying to extract the dominant color from google cloud vision API -
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop

The below piece of function sometimes extracts the correct RGB values but sometimes it extracts incorrect RGB values as well. What should i change in the below code so that it always picks the dominant color with highest RGB percentage. i.e the first RGB value from the left.

```
def dominat_color(image):
    response = client.image_properties(image=image)
    props = response.image_properties_annotation

    max_frac=0.0
    #print('Properties:', props.dominant_colors.colors[0].red,",",props.dominant_colors.colors[0].green,",",props.dominant_colors.colors[0].blue,",",dominant_colors.colors[0].pixel_fraction)

    for color in props.dominant_colors.colors:

        var1=float(color.pixel_fraction)*100
    #var1=float(color.percent)

        if (var1 > max_frac):
            max_frac=var1
            var2=int(color.color.red)
            var3=int(color.color.green)
            var4=int(color.color.blue)
            #print("\nRGB: ", var2,",",var3,",",var4,",", (var1))


    if response.error.message:
        raise Exception(
            '{}\nFor more info on error messages, check: '
            'https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors'.format(
                response.error.message))
    return var2,var3,var4

creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(r'xxxx.json') #credentials
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(credentials=creds,)
```

```
Sample Output:

Image_name   Red   Green  Blue

k1.jpg       240   125     16
```

The red,green and blue values should be the left most RGB values
in gcp --> https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop
under properties tab i am just trying to extract the first RGB values from the left.

Comment: Hi @Sasi, can you clarify your requirement by providing sample output?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar i have mentioned the sample output that is expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement, you can use a list in python to store the values and find the dominant value from the left. You can check the below  sample code which you can use for your use case.

**Code :**

```
def dominat_color(image):
    from google.cloud import vision
    import io
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    image_uri = image
    image = vision.Image() # Py2+3 if hasattr(vision, 'Image') else vision.types.Image()
    image.source.image_uri = image_uri

    response = client.image_properties(image=image)
    props = response.image_properties_annotation
    
    
    #print('Properties:', props.dominant_colors.colors[0].red,",",props.dominant_colors.colors[0].green,",",props.dominant_colors.colors[0].blue,",",dominant_colors.colors[0].pixel_fraction)
    max_frac=0.0
    lst = []
    for color in props.dominant_colors.colors:

        var1=float(color.pixel_fraction)*100
        if (var1 > max_frac):
            max_frac = var1
                
            var2=int(color.color.red)
            lst.append(var2)
            var3=int(color.color.green)
            lst.append(var3)
            var4=int(color.color.blue)
            lst.append(var4)

    rmax = max(lst)
    index = lst.index(rmax)
    print(lst[index],lst[index+1],lst[index+2])
    
    
    if response.error.message:
        raise Exception(
            '{}\nFor more info on error messages, check: '
            'https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors'.format(
                response.error.message))
        
dominat_color(image_path)
```

**Output :**

[image]